# .NET Core DI, ways of passing parameters to constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, .net-core, ioc-container

Having the following service constructor

```
public class Service : IService
{
     public Service(IOtherService service1, IAnotherOne service2, string arg)
     {    
     }
}
```

What are the choices of passing the parameters using .NET Core IOC mechanism

```
services.AddSingleton<IOtherService , OtherService>();
services.AddSingleton<IAnotherOne , AnotherOne>();
services.AddSingleton<IService>(x =>
    new Service(
        services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<IOtherService>(),
        services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<IAnotherOne >(),
        ""));
```

Is there any other way ?

Comment: Change your design. Extract the arg into a Parameter Object and inject that.

Answer (score 326, accepted):

The expression parameter (*x* in this case) of the factory delegate is an `IServiceProvider`.

Use that to resolve the dependencies:

```
_serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IService>(x => 
    new Service(x.GetRequiredService<IOtherService>(),
                x.GetRequiredService<IAnotherOne>(), 
                ""));
```

The factory delegate is a delayed invocation. Whenever the type is to be resolved, it will pass the completed provider as the delegate parameter.

Comment: yes, this is the way I'm doing it right now, but is there any other way ? more elegant maybe ? I mean It would look a little weird to have other parameters that are registered services. I am looking for something more like register the services normally and only pass the non-service arguments, in this case the arg. Something like Autofac does  `.WithParameter("argument", "");`

Comment: No you are building the provider manually, which is bad. The delegate is a delayed invocation. When ever the type is to be resolved it will pass the completed provider as the delegate parameter.

Comment: @Nkosi: Have a look at [ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.activatorutilities.createinstance?view=aspnetcore-2.1#Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_ActivatorUtilities_CreateInstance_System_IServiceProvider_System_Type_System_Object___), its part of the `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions` package (so no container specific dependencies)

Comment: And what about parameters override at resolve time? Not every param is available at register time. Something similar as https://docs.autofac.org/en/stable/resolve/parameters.html

Comment: Have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection for service registering methods,

Comment: is the lifetime of the `new Service` then not maintained by the DI framework in this scenario?

Comment: @gusmallysupportsMonica that is correct. It is not maintained since it was not created by the framework. However, in this particular scenario `Service` is a singleton and will be around for the lifetime of the container.

Answer (score 170):

The recommended way to achieve this is to use the [Options pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options) - note that this applies to any .NET Core/5 application, not just ASP.NET Core. But there are use cases where it's impractical (e.g. when parameters are only known at runtime, not at startup/compile-time) or you need to dynamically replace a dependency.

It's very useful when you need to replace a single dependency (be it a string, integer or another type of dependency) or when using a 3rd-party library which accepts only string/integer parameters and you require runtime parameters.

You could try [`ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<T>(IServiceProvider, Object[])`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.activatorutilities.createinstance#Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_ActivatorUtilities_CreateInstance__1_System_IServiceProvider_System_Object___) as a shortcut rather than resolving every single dependency manually:

```
_serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IService>(x => 
    ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<Service>(x, "");
);
```

The parameters to pass to your service's constructor (the `object[]` parameter to `CreateInstance<T>`/`CreateInstance`) allows you to specify parameters that should be injected directly, as opposed to resolved from the service provider. They are applied from left to right as they appear (i.e. first string will be replaced with the first string-typed parameter of the type to be instantiated).

`ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<Service>` is used in many places to resolve service and replace one of the default registrations for this single activation.

For example, if you have a class named `MyService`, and it has `IOtherService`, `ILogger<MyService>` as dependencies and you want to resolve the service but replace the default service of `IOtherService` (say it's `OtherServiceA`) with `OtherServiceB`, you could do something like:

```
myService = ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<Service>(serviceProvider,
    new OtherServiceB());
```

Then the first parameter of `IOtherService` will get `OtherServiceB` injected, rather than `OtherServiceA` - but the remaining parameters will come from the service provider.

This is helpful when you have many dependencies and want just to treat a single one specially (i.e. replace a database-specific provider with a value configured during the request or for a specific user, something you only know at runtime and/or during a request - not when the application is built/started).

If performance is a concern, you can use [`ActivatorUtilities.CreateFactory(Type, Type[])`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.activatorutilities.createfactory#Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_ActivatorUtilities_CreateFactory_System_Type_System_Type___) to create a factory method instead. [GitHub reference](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/issues/1570#issue-303926566) and [benchmark](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/pull/1643).

This is useful when the type is resolved very frequently (such as in SignalR and other high request scenarios). Basically, you'd create an `ObjectFactory` via

```
var myServiceFactory = ActivatorUtilities.CreateFactory(typeof(MyService), new Type[] { typeof(IOtherService), });
```

then cache it (as a variable etc.) and invoke it where needed:

```
MyService myService = myServiceFactory(serviceProvider, myServiceOrParameterTypeToReplace);
```

This all works perfectly with primitive types too - here's an example I tested with:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var services = new ServiceCollection();
        services.AddTransient<HelloWorldService>();
        services.AddTransient(p => p.ResolveWith<DemoService>("Tseng", "Stackoverflow"));

        var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

        var demoService = provider.GetRequiredService<DemoService>();

        Console.WriteLine($"Output: {demoService.HelloWorld()}");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class DemoService
{
    private readonly HelloWorldService helloWorldService;
    private readonly string firstname;
    private readonly string lastname;

    public DemoService(HelloWorldService helloWorldService, string firstname, string lastname)
    {
        this.helloWorldService = helloWorldService ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(helloWorldService));
        this.firstname = firstname ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(firstname));
        this.lastname = lastname ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(lastname));
    }

    public string HelloWorld()
    {
        return this.helloWorldService.Hello(firstname, lastname);
    }
}

public class HelloWorldService
{
    public string Hello(string name) => $"Hello {name}";
    public string Hello(string firstname, string lastname) => $"Hello {firstname} {lastname}";
}

// Just a helper method to shorten code registration code
static class ServiceProviderExtensions
{
    public static T ResolveWith<T>(this IServiceProvider provider, params object[] parameters) where T : class => 
        ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<T>(provider, parameters);
}
```

Prints

> ```
> Output: Hello Tseng Stackoverflow
> ```

Comment: This is also how ASP.NET Core instantiates the Controllers by default [ControllerActivatorProvider](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/2.2.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/Controllers/ControllerActivatorProvider.cs#L56-L57), they are not directly resolved from the IoC (unless `.AddControllersAsServices` is used, which replaces the `ControllerActivatorProvider` with `ServiceBasedControllerActivator`

Comment: Worth noting that using this **outside of the DI framework** (The usage in this question looks fine to me) would be the [service locator anti-pattern](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/).

Comment: @Wouter: No you couldn't. The constructor in question has 3 constructor parameters. When you `new` it, you need to pass every single constructor parameter. With ActivatorUtils, you pass only the parameters that **should NOT come from the container**. This is especially useful when the string/int parameters are determined at runtime, not at start time (which is where DI container is configured and can't change afterwards). The code is for demonstration, to show, that you can inject runtime parameters (or even service instances) while the rest comes from DI container

Comment: With the main point being to avoid to have to `provider.GetRequiredService<T>()` every single dependency of the given class, which also breaks your code when you add an additional parameter to the constructor

Comment: This last Program where you services.AddTransient(p => p.ResolveWith<DemoService>("Tseng", "Stackoverflow")); seems pointless because you could just use  services.AddTransient(sp => new DemoService(p.GetRequiredService<HelloWorldService>(), "Tseng", "Stackoverflow"))

Comment: @Tseng thanks for responding... I missed the extra (first) parameter which I would just resolve myself without the activatorutilities. So how to get the values at runtime as in your example they are hardcoded.

Comment: You'd usually make some kind of factory, such as `MyServiceFactory`, that gets `IServiceProvider` injected, and resolve it from there (ActivatorUtils need ServiceProvder to resolve the dependencies). If the parameters can be obtained from the services (i.e. `IHttpContextAccessor`, you could call the factory method in the registration: `services.AddScoped<MyService>(provider => provider.GetRequiredService<MyServiceFactory>().Create())`

Comment: @Benrobot pretty sure it does. You should validate your claims. This is the   overload which accepts a factory, not the overload that accepts an instance. Big difference, since factory created instances are registered for disposal if they implement IDisposable

Comment: @Benrobot: I already told you, `AddSingleton(s => new Service())` and `AddSingleton(new Service())` is a huge difference. First one instantiates an instance of `Service` and register that this instance should be returned. `AddSingleton(sp => new Service())` on the other sides, is a factory which tells the .NET Core DI how to instantiate it when required. When that happens (when the factory is called) the Microsoft.Extensions.DependecyInjection checks if the object implements `IDisposable` and register it for disposable and will be disposed when the container is disposed

Answer (score 34):

If you feel uncomfortable with newing the service, you could use the `Parameter Object` pattern.

So extract the string parameter into its own type

```
public class ServiceArgs
{
   public string Arg1 {get; set;}
}
```

And the constructor will now look like

```
public Service(IOtherService service1, 
               IAnotherOne service2, 
               ServiceArgs args)
{

}
```

And the setup

```
_serviceCollection.AddSingleton<ServiceArgs>(_ => new ServiceArgs { Arg1 = ""; });
_serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IOtherService , OtherService>();
_serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IAnotherOne , AnotherOne>();
_serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IService, Service>();
```

The first benefit is if you need to change the Service constructor and add new services to it, then you don't have to change the `new Service(...` calls. Another benefit is the setup is a bit cleaner.

For a constructor with a single parameter or two, this might be too much though.

Comment: It would be more intuitive for complex parameters to use the [Options pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-2.2) and is the recommended way for options pattern, however is less suitable for parameters only know at runtime (i.e. from a request or a claim)

Answer (score 6):

You can inject dependencies with this process also

```
_serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IOtherService , OtherService>();
_serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IAnotherOne , AnotherOne>();
_serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IService>(x=>new Service( x.GetService<IOtherService>(), x.GetService<IAnotherOne >(), "" ));
```