# Reliable way to get the type of class from within a service, instantiated through .Net Core DI

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection

Essentially, I want to be able to determine the namespace of the caller class inside my service. The service instantiation happens with the default ASP.NET Core DI. A further obstacle may arise because I want to determine the caller inside the constructor of the base class and not directly in the instantiated service.

I suspect I know the answer to my question, but if It can happen, it wouldn't be the crazier thing I've seen.

### Edit

#### Sample code

```cs
// First caller
namespace Example.Assembly.One
{
    public class CallerOne
    {
        consctructor(Service service)

        void WhichCallerAmI() { return this.service.ReturnCaller() }
        ...
    }   
}

// Second caller
namespace Example.Assembly.Two
{
    public class CallerTwo
    {
        consctructor(Service service)

        void WhichCallerAmI() { return this.service.ReturnCaller() }
        ...
    }   
}


// Service
namespace Example.Service
{
    public class Service : BaseService
    {
        consctructor() : base()

        public void ReturnCaller()
        {
            if (this.namespace == "Example.Assembly.One")
            {
                return "First caller";
            }

            return "Second caller";
        }  
    }   
}

// Base service
namespace Example.Service
{
    public class BaseService
    {
        consctructor(Service service)
        {
            // Determine namespace of caller here
            this.namespace = <insert-answer-here>
        }
    }   
}

// demo
// These callers can be controllers or other services
var firstCaller = new CallerOne() 
var secondCaller = new CallerTwo();

// firstResult now contains "First Caller"
var firstResult = firstCaller.WhichCallerAmI();

// secondResult now contains "Second Caller";
var secondResult = secondCaller.WhichCallerAmI();
```

#### XY problem

The *Callers* from the example represent data services in separete micro-service web projects, each using separate database. The problem I am trying to work around is to reuse the same service code for one entity, duplicated in all or some of the separate databases. My idea is to inject the relevant `DbContext` based on the namespace of the caller class, since we follow strict naming conventions either way.

Comment: This might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that clarifies your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Why do you care about this? This *reverses* dependency injection. What is the real problem you want to solve? The easy way to do this at runtime would be to use eg [StackTrace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stacktrace?view=netcore-3.0) to find the calling method but why do that? If the caller's type matters, why not pass it as a generic type parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have a class:

```
public class Consumer
{
    public Consumer(Provider provider)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

And this class has the following dependency:

```
public class Provider : BaseProvider
{
    public Provider()
        : base()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

And this dependency has a base class:

```
public class BaseProvider
{
    public BaseProvider()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

And now in the constructor of `BaseProvider` you want to know for which caller it is being initialized?

You can't.

The dependency injection framework will be initializing the `Provider` service *before* instantiating the `Consumer` class. So you won't be able to obtain this information, especially not from the stack trace.

This is an XY problem. If you need to know *who* is calling a class, you're doing something wrong. What you *could* be looking for, is a parameterized constructor in `Provider`, that gets called with different parameters depending on who needs it, in order to alter its behavior. But that's a different question altogether.

For the latter, see for example [.NET Core DI, ways of passing parameters to constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53884417/net-core-di-ways-of-passing-parameters-to-constructor).