# How to use a Service or DbContext inside DbCommandInterceptor?

Tags: c#, ef-core-3.0

I have an application that syncs data from a MySql database to a SQL Server database.

Considering those two DbContext services:

```cs
services.AddDbContext<SqlServerContext>(options => options
    .UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("SqlServer")));

services.AddDbContext<MySqlContext>(options => options
    .UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MySql"))
    .AddInterceptors(new MySqlInterceptor()));
```

In the `MySqlInterceptor()`; I want to inject/resolve/use a `Service` or even the `SqlServerContext`, in order to get configurations to modify the `CommandText`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @vasil mentioned in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58855624/655605):

> Depending on the method you are going to override, you will receive
>   [CommandEventData](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-ef-core-3-0-and-ef-6-3-general-availability/#interception-of-database-operations) object in the method definition which has the
>   `DbContext` as property.

In my case though, I wanted to resolve a service that used **another** DbContext, which proved to be cumbersome; so instead I ended up putting the settings I needed into appsettings.json, and used `IConfiguration` service to get the setting value and sent it to the Interceptor constructor:

```
services.AddDbContext<MySqlContext>(options => options
    .UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MySql"))
    .AddInterceptors(new MySqlInterceptor(Configuration["SettingValue"])));
```

---

**Note**: If you landed on this answer and was looking for a way to resolve a service inside the `ConfigureService` method, without calling `BuildServiceProvider` which, like David Fowler says on a [Github issue](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/14587#issuecomment-545723876), you'd be:

> building the container while trying to build it

and you'll end up having:

> 2 containers and one of them will never be disposed.

You can do what Nkosi suggests in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53884452/655605):

```
services.AddScoped<IService>(x => 
    new Service(x.GetRequiredService<IOtherService>(),
                x.GetRequiredService<IAnotherOne>(), 
                ""));
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the method you are going to override you will receive [`CommandEventData`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-ef-core-3-0-and-ef-6-3-general-availability/#interception-of-database-operations) object in the method definition which has the `DbContext` as property.

As to the services and configurations you can configure the interceptor before registration.
Instead of this:

```
services.AddDbContext<MySqlContext>(options => options
    .UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MySql"))
    .AddInterceptors(new MySqlInterceptor()));
```

you can do

```
var interceptor = new MySqlInterceptor(service1, service2 ... etc);
services.AddDbContext<MySqlContext>(options => options
 .UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MySql"))
 .AddInterceptors(interceptor))
```

---

**How to resolve the interceptor instance:**
If you need to auto-wire the dependencies of the interceptor you can do the following

```
services.AddTransient<Service1>();
services.AddTransient<Service2>();
services.AddTransient<MySqlInterceptor>();
// resolve the instalce of the interceptor
var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
var interceptor = serviceProvider.GetService<MySqlInterceptor>();
// configure mysql context and interceptor
services.AddDbContext<MySqlContext>(options => options
 .UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MySql"))
 .AddInterceptors(interceptor))
```

Comment: A pardon my lack of knowledge: Is there a way that the the instance of `MySqlInterceptor` also get service1 injected? Like `MySqlInterceptor(IService1)`?

Comment: Throws a warning: `Warning ASP0000 Calling 'BuildServiceProvider' from application code results in an additional copy of singleton services being created. Consider alternatives such as dependency injecting services as parameters to 'Configure'.`

Comment: This is a minor observation but worth mentioning: the first suggestion doesn't provide much, you can always `.AddInterceptors(MySqlInterceptor(service1)))`

Comment: if you think about it, ConfigureService is for container setup really, so creating a concrete inside of it defeats the purpose.

Comment: I have an idea but it is too late and have to get some sleep; if I get something useful I’ll maybe post in an answer, we’ll see. Thanks for taking the time looking into this.

Comment: @Yes i agree. It is useful when you have complex dependency graph (for example Servcie1 depends on another services ... etc) so you don't have to build the graph by hand. Post your idea i am interested in your solution.